# Can't add properly index for each appended divs on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see my demo [here](https://codepen.io/ChicagoJostik/pen/NWxQNYw).
I have simple **html**:

```
<input type="file" id="files" multiple>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

So when user choose image he can preview it, and when he click on upload button and add another images he also will see in preview that this images was added.

My problem that I want to add for each appended `div` a `data attribute` with `index` value of it.

**My js:**

```
$("#files").on("change", previewFiles);

function previewFiles() {
    var preview = $('.preview');
    var files   = $(this)[0].files;

    function readAndPreview(file) {

        if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                var conta = $('<div></div>').addClass("preview__image");

                var img = $('<img>');
                img.attr('src', event.target.result);
                img.attr('title', file.name);
                img.appendTo(conta);

                conta.appendTo( preview );
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

    }

    if (files) {
        [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
    }
    
    var child = preview.find(".preview__image");
    child.each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("data-index", index);
    });
    
}
```

In my code there is a problem, when user choose image for the first time, `data attribute` is not created, if he upload image for the second time, appended before `div` or divs which was first will get `data attribute`, but new appended `div` or divs not.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I know that my input is clearing its value before uploading another images. All I want is related to preview block. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're trying to talk to an element that is not yet in the DOM - because `onload` is an asynchronous event.

In other words, the element with `.preview__image` does not get added until AFTER you're running `preview.find('.preview__image')`.

There's various ways round this. One would be to use `Promise.all()` and convert your reader function to return a promise that gets resolved only once the `onload` callback has completed.

We could attach a `then()` to `Promise.all`, but more elegant would be to use `await`, which means we'll need to make your outer function asynchronous, by prefixing `async` to it.

All in all (I've commented the key changes):

```
$("#files").on("change", previewFiles);

async function previewFiles() { //<-- prefix with async

    var preview = $('.preview');
    var files   = $(this)[0].files;

    function readAndPreview(file) {

        return new Promise(res => { //<-- reader func now returns promise...

            if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var conta = $('<div></div>').addClass("preview__image");
                    var img = $('<img>');
                    img.attr('src', event.target.result);
                    img.attr('title', file.name);
                    img.appendTo(conta);
                    conta.appendTo( preview );
                    res(); //...which is resolved once onload is complete
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

        });

    }

    //now let's have a master promise that waits for the sub-promises to resolve
    await Promise.all([...files].map(file => readAndPreview(file)));

    //now we can talk to the updated DOM
    var child = preview.find(".preview__image");
    child.each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("data-index", index);
    });

}
```